# Show with echo if a post has two or more categories

Tags: posts, categories

I am not exactly an expert in php and less in wordpress. I wanted to know if they are so kind that I have a fault. I explain, my problem is that I want to display a div with echo in a post if it has these two categories (or more). I am attaching the code. Thank you very much and greetings!

```
<?php 
        $bflower = "This is a A";
        $bmammal = "This is a B";
        $cflower = "This is a C";
        $cmammal = "This is a D";
        if(has_category(array('chicken', 'mammal'))){
            echo $cmammal; }
        elseif (has_category(array('jasmin', 'rose'))) {
            echo $cplant; }
        elseif (has_category(array('aloe vera', 'jeran'))) {
            echo $bplant; }
        elseif (has_category(array('rabbit', 'cow'))) {
            echo $banimal; }
        else
            echo "No";
?>
```

Comment: First, where do you expect to place the code?

Comment: In the single.php

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, if placed within the Loop - after, typically, `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` in a single.php file - the code will work as follows:

- The `has_category( array( 'x', 'y' ) )` condition will be satisfied if the post is in either x or y, or both, regardless of whether it is in any other categories (assuming an otherwise unmodified main query and no other conditions).
- In your example, if the post was in both "jeran" and "cow," then
  `$bplant` would be echoed, but not `$banimal.` I think you probably
  already understand why.
- If a post must have **both** of the two categories, then you'll have
  to work the logic out accordingly- e.g., `if ( has_category( 'x' ) &&   has_category( 'y' ) )`, etc.

You might also conceivably run into problems with unique approaches to "single post pages."